# Replace Class files in the server stack

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Is there a way to find out the java classes loaded in the server stack and replace the same with the latest version of the same without restarting the web or application server?

Comment: Did you mean hot deployment?

Comment: yes.hot deployment of selective classes. The user should be able to do it.Not the server by itslef

Comment: Which webserver are you using?

Comment: I want to do this for Tomcat/Websphere

Comment: try this http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-deploy

Comment: Thanks a lot Pradeep. Taking a look...

Answer (score 0):

On Tomcat, there is an attribute called reloadable which support automatic reloading of changed classes/libraries. From Tomcat site:

```
reloadable
```

"Set to true if you want Catalina to monitor classes in /WEB-INF/classes/ and /WEB-INF/lib for   changes, and automatically reload the web application if a change is detected. This feature is very useful during application development, but it requires significant runtime overhead and is not recommended for use on deployed production applications. That's why the default setting for this attribute is false. You can use the Manager web application, however, to trigger reloads of deployed applications on demand."

Sample usages is (Add following line in server.xml file):

```
<Context path="/webdev" docBase="/webdev" reloadable="true"></Context>
```

for more info, please refer http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html